# spring JPA) how to save an entity with only foreign key provided and service considered?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I am developing web application on Spring-MVC with Hibernate.

My application has Controller - Service Layer - DAO Layer.

I have the following entity-relationship.

[image]

As you can see, user can have many comments (one - many relationship)

When user writes comment and saves it, my web service will get "user_id, comment" from user web request.

Then I try to save comment but I don't have user entity to save with.

So I should find user entity first with user_id and set it to new comment object, then save it through CommentDao.save(commentEntity).

Then should my CommentService call UserService to get user entity or  should my CommentService have UserDAO to get user entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You should first try to get the user entity of that user id which give you a chance to validate if an user with this ID is really exist. If it does not exist , you can report the error.

There is no strict rule about whether the CommentService must call UserService or UserDAO to get an user entity. It depend on what is the differences between your `UserService#getUser()` and `UserDAO#getUser()` . If they do not have any differences , I prefer to keep it simple and reduce once extra layer by calling `UserDAO#getUser()` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The DAO layer's main goal is to handle the details of the persistence mechanism. While the service layer stands on top of it to handle business requirements.